# Почему условие if не срабатывает и транзакция подтверждается?

Tags: mysql, sql

Сама транзакция:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `prog_transact`(vprog_name varchar(255), yprog_cy year, vprog_purp varchar (255), vprog_dt varchar (255), ilic_id int, vprog_vers varchar (63), vprog_ff varchar (255), vprog_website varchar (511), vprog_interface varchar(127), iarch_id int, idev_id int, ipl_id int, ios_id int)
begin
declare iprog_id int;
declare exit handler for sqlexception
begin
rollback;
select 'transaction not commited: sqlexception';
show errors;
end;
start transaction;
if ilic_id=null or iarch_id=null or idev_id=null or ipl_id=null or ios_id=null then
rollback;
select 'transaction not commited: nulldata';
end if;
insert into program (name, creation_year, purpose, dist_type, lic_id, version, file_formats, website, interface) values (vprog_name, yprog_cy, vprog_purp, vprog_dt, ilic_id, vprog_vers, vprog_ff, vprog_website, vprog_interface);
select max(id) into iprog_id from program;
insert into arch_prog (arch_id, prog_id) values (iarch_id, iprog_id);
insert into dev_prog (dev_id, prog_id) values (idev_id, iprog_id);
insert into pl_prog (pl_id, prog_id) values (ipl_id, iprog_id);
insert into os_prog (os_id, prog_id) values (ios_id, iprog_id);
commit;
end
```

По идее, если последние переменные в процедуре заданы как `null`'ы, то транзакция должна откатиться. Как бы не так!

```
call prog_transact('Spore',2008,'Компьютерная игра','коммерческое',11,'1.05.1',null,'spore.com','графический', null, null, null, null);
```

... и  транзакция успешно подтверждается!
Почему не проверяется условие выше?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя сравнивать значение с `NULL` при помощи оператора `=`. Сравнение с неопределенной величиной всегда неопределенная величина. Для того, чтобы выяснить принимает ли величина значение `NULL`, используйте специальный оператор `IS NULL` и его отрицательную форму `IN NOT NULL`

```
SELECT NULL IS NULL, NULL IS NOT NULL, NULL = NULL, NULL <> NULL;
+--------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
| NULL IS NULL | NULL IS NOT NULL | NULL = NULL | NULL <> NULL |
+--------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
|            1 |                0 |        NULL |         NULL |
+--------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
```